# HTTP being redirected to HTTPS [CentOS][Apache]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I am having a issue after I restarted by apache server . After spending hours and hours of researching this issue, I decided it to post it here.

Basically, I stopped my Apache server using the cmd `service httpd stop` and typed in http://158.69.225.137/ into my browser and it looks like even though the apache server is down, the IP is being redirected to https://158.69.225.137/. I tried editing my `.htaccess` file already and it will not disable `HTTPS` while the server is running.

I followed this tutorial to setup my apache server. I enabled `.htaccess` in the proccess.

Thanks,
Faraaz

Comment: is your RewriteEngine On now? Try to change AllowOverride none to disable .htaccess to debug

Comment: @zairwolf I turned AllowOverride to none but RewriteEngine is not on.

Comment: Did you enable HSTS at some point? If so, ithe HTTP-> HTTPS redirect may have been stored in your browser. I do not redirected to https://... when I type in http://158.69.225.137/

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same problem: I'm running a website that uses Apache and Cloudflare and had tried turning off automatic HTTPS redirection both in Cloudflare and in my site's Apache config, but I kept getting redirected to HTTPS anyway, and I couldn't understand why.

Anand Bhat's suggestion appears to have been what was happening: my browser had cached the redirect.  I tried using an incognito window and was not redirected, and clearing the browser cache stopped the redirect from happening in a regular (non-incognito) browser window.

To clear the relevant cache in Chrome, go to Settings → Advanced → Clear browsing data → Cached images and files